# How to include the comma when uploading CSV in php

Tags: php, mysql, csv

i am trying to upload values for mysql and i seem to have a problem with commas, it considers it as the end for every column. or i dont know how to explain it but when i have multiple commas in lets say a text field, it goes to the next column and so on breaking the format.

here is my code. and i am new with this so i hope an explanation would be nice.

```
//get the csv file 
    $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name]; 
    $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

    //loop through the csv file and insert into database 
    do { 
        if ($data[0]) { 
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO inventory (prod_brand, prod_name, prod_category, prod_price, prod_desc, prod_quantity) VALUES 
                ( 
                    '".addslashes($data[0])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[1])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[2])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[3])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[4])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[5])."'  
                ) 
            "); 
        } 
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//get the csv file 
    $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name]; 
    $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

    //loop through the csv file and insert into database 
    do { 
        if ($data[0]) { 
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO inventory (prod_brand, prod_name, prod_category, prod_price, prod_desc, prod_quantity) VALUES 
                ( 
                    '".addslashes($data[0]).",', 
                    '".addslashes($data[1]).",', 
                    '".addslashes($data[2]).",',
                    '".addslashes($data[3]).",',
                    '".addslashes($data[4]).",',
                    '".addslashes($data[5])."'  
                ) 
            "); 
        } 
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"));
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I want to suggest you that if your table data contains Comma(,) then you should export your CSV with different delimiters like tabs, and enclose column data in quotes.

then you can see in `fgetcsv` function's prototype that you can explicitly specify the delimiters it looks like this:

```
array fgetcsv ( resource $handle [, int $length = 0 [, string $delimiter = "," [, string $enclosure = '"' [, string $escape = "\\" ]]]] )
```

use delimiter according to your export and then use the same code that you are using.

When you export you can use following command in command prompt to use custom delimiters

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM table_name
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/table_name.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

in phpmyadmin also you can specify custom delimiters.